# Bad performance using spark against cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-spark

Currently we're challenging our architecture while using apache spark against our cassandra db because we're experiencing a really bad read performance.

The hardware where the spark & cassandra takes place is a cloud server with 16GB Memory with 8 Cores and is using a SSD for the OS.

Cassandra 'data_file_directories' is set to another hdd whose test-results were with `hdparm -tT`:

```
Timing cached reads:   13140 MB in  1.99 seconds = 6604.42 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 428 MB in  3.00 seconds = 142.65 MB/sec
```

The target cf in cassandra:

```
CREATE TABLE test.stats (
day timestamp,
received timestamp,
target inet,
via inet,
prefix blob,
rtt decimal,
PRIMARY KEY (day, received, target, via)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (received ASC, target ASC, via ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"NONE", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'min_threshold': '4', 'class':     'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy',     'max_threshold': '32'}
    AND compression = {}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

We are currently using Cassandra 2.1.6 with the java datastax driver (2.1.6) and the spark java connector (spark-cassandra-connector_2.10, version 1.4.0-M2).

The Spark process currently has one worker with `conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "2G");` set.

Starting a simple spark job to read all rows of one explicit partition key (which has round about 83.520.000 rows) via a submit/or serialized-driver took 17minutes.

The job simply writes all rows to a file, which has a final size of 1,2G.

Here is the driver code:

```
CassandraTableScanJavaRDD<EchoRepliesBean> cassandraTable2 = null;
    switch (timespanMode)
    {
        case SIX_HOURS:
            Calendar calendarDay = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            calendarDay.setTimeInMillis(now);
            calendarDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            calendarDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            calendarDay.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calendarDay.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            Timestamp tsEnd = new Timestamp(calendarDay.getTimeInMillis());
            calendarDay.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
            Timestamp tsStart = new Timestamp(calendarDay.getTimeInMillis());
            System.out.println(tsStart);
            cassandraTable2 = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("test", "stats", mapRowTo(EchoRepliesBean.class))
                                               .where("day = ?", tsStart);
            break;
        default:
            /* make compiler happy */
            // cassandraTable = null;
    } 
    cassandraTable2.saveAsTextFile("/opt/out_TEST_" + System.currentTimeMillis());

    sc.stop();
```

This is strange, any help or ideas for further debugging would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you try this with a smaller partition?  Does the performance suddenly fall off after the partition has a certain number of rows?  Is the spark worker running on the Cassandra node?  Did you try increasing the memory allocated to the spark worker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possible ways to improve performance:

1. Increase the parallelism by partitioning the data on multiple nodes.  Since you are partitioning by day, you have a large number of rows in one partition on one node.  This is forcing the reads and writes to be a serial operation.  If you partitioned by hour, then your data could be spread across multiple nodes and multiple spark workers.
2. I suspect your day partition is too big to fit into the single spark worker's memory, which may be causing some swapping of data to disk.  Using smaller partitions, giving the spark worker more memory, or using more spark workers would avoid that.
3. Make sure your spark workers are running on the Cassandra nodes and not on separate machines.  If the workers are on separate machines then there will be a lot of network overhead to shuffle the data from the nodes to the workers.
4. Make sure your cloud server is using local storage for Cassandra and not network storage.

To debug I would try running your test on a partition with only one row in it.  If that performs badly then there is something wrong with your machine setup.  If that performs well, then increase the number of rows in the partition until you see a sharp drop off in performance.

Comment: 1. This will be something we will do in the medium term.
2. We changed our partition to hourly, which results in about 2 million rows.
This sized down the duration to 26seconds! :)
3. We already had that. 
4. Dito.
Thanks Jim! This helped a lot.

What is still bothering me is the resulting "speed". The size of the outputfile is about 100MByte which is not that much spending 26s on.

Comment: You feel 26s is still too slow?  Remember that spark is still a batch job and not a real time query.  There is an overhead involved in spinning up the job.

Comment: The problem is that we do not have experiences, that's why iam asking. :)

Answer (score 0):

A bug was introduced into Cassandra 2.1.5 and corrected in 2.1.8 that caused significantly degraded spark performance: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9637

Upgrading to latest (2.1.8) will likely greatly increase your spark related performance.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, we updated our cassandra. But i may not say if that had a major impact, or if the smaller partition had more impact on the performance.